# AngularJS and Symfony2 Routing - FOSJsRoutingBundle

Tags: angularjs, symfony, routes, href

I am doing a project in Symfony2 and Angular JS.
I have installed FOSJsRoutingBundle for routing purposes.
This is my home page - http://localhost/stars/admin/ and i am doing in wamp server.

[home page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFXxv.png)

Home page word fine. You can see a side bar which holds some links like sun,  stars, home etc..
My requirement is when i click on these links, it should use angularjs routing, not the default routing..
How can i acheive this..
my layout.html.twig

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
        <div class="container">
            <!--Header Bar-->
            <div id="header"></div>
            <!--Side Bar-->
            <div id="sidebar">
                <ul class="sidebar-menu">
                    <li class="active treeview">
                        <a href="#">
                            <span>Home</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#sun">
                            <span>Sun</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#/stars">
                            <span>Stars</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#/planets">
                            <span>Planets</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#/moon">
                            <span>Moon</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!--Main Content-->
            <div id="content" ng-view>{% block body %}{% endblock %} </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    <!--Angular JS-->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/angular.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.5/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        Routing.generate('_home_url');
    </script>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
        app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider.
              when('', {templateUrl: Routing.generate('_home_url')}).
              when('/sun', {templateUrl: Routing.generate('_sun_url')}).
              otherwise({redirectTo: ''});
            }]);
    </script>
```

my routing.yml

```
# app/config/routing.yml
fos_js_routing:
    resource: "@FOSJsRoutingBundle/Resources/config/routing/routing.xml"

_home_url:
    pattern: admin/
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:admin/index:list }
    options:
        expose: true

_sun_url:
    pattern: admin/sun
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:admin/sun:index }
    options:
        expose: true
```

my config.yml

```
fos_js_routing:
    routes_to_expose: [ _home_url,_sun_url ]
```

Please help me, i am new user in symfony2 and angularJS..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ngHref` directive see [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref)
reference

```
<a ng-href="/sun"><span>Sun</span></a>
```

Alternatively you can use [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router)
alterative for angular `ngRoute` and you can use `ui-sref` directive for the links see [this](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref) reference

Comment: link is not properly working frnd.. When  we hover mouse on those texts, its jus a text not a link..